# SignalR not invoking result with DNS alias on client

Tags: signalr

I connect to my server, which is load balanced for an alias to point to 2 servers, 01 & 02 and it round-robins connections for arguments sake. I can connect to the hub without a problem, and I can even send stuff to the server, but when it goes to return it to the client, I never get my methods invoked. If I bypass the load balancer and use the server name explicitly, it always works just fine.

I'm even tracing it, and I send back the message from the exact originating server with the Clients.Client(clientId).completeJob(stuff), and that executes fine on the server, but if I ContinueWith, it never gets finished.

Oh, and it's connected with server sent events. Am I missing something or is this just not supported?

Comment: As an update, it's now communicating with the client through the alias, but not for .NET client to server, that is still requiring the use of a concrete name for some odd reason.

Comment: Any update on this? Would be nice to see a bit of code to see how you tackled this and any environment configurations that went with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server-sent events establishes a long running connection, but unlike WebSockets, it isn't bidirectional. The connection can only be used to push data to the client.

SignalR uses regular XHRs to send data from clients when the WebSocket transport is unavailable. This means that the load balancer will likely route client-to-server hub method invocations to a server different than the one the client originally established a server-sent event connection with.

The server executing `Clients.Client(clientId).completeJob(stuff)` likely doesn't own the connection that would allow it to push a message to the specified client. (Though returning a value from a hub method on the server will send data back to the client via the same connection that invoked the method.)

SignalR can work behind a load balancer. It just requires a little more setup so all the SignalR servers can communicate with each other via a backplane such as Service Bus or Redis. This allows messages to get dispatched to the server that owns the server-to-client connection.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Azure-service-bus details how you can setup a Service Bus backplane on Azure.

Comment: Documentation on the Redis setup was a bit out of date, but it was remarkably simple, and worked great. Thanks!